# Microsoft Excel- Invert a 0/1 value or leave empty if no value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm ran into an issue while trying to do some work in an excel doc. I have created a column to count the number of flags in other columns. One of the flags I created simply inverts the value of another flag. I'm aware there's no reason for the new column if all I'm doing is inverting the value of a column that already exists, but space isn't an issue and in this case it's much easier for to create a 2nd column to keep things easier to understand.

The new column I created is based off a "consent given" column where the value is 1 if consent has been given, 0 if it has not been given, or empty if we don't have that information. I want my flag counter to count when consent has NOT been given, but I can't figure out a formula to set the value as 0 if consent has been given, 1 if it has not been given, or empty if no information. I can easily say 1 for no consent and 0 for consent or no information, but I want the no information columns to be empty. I can't use an empty string in the case of no information because that breaks my flag counter sum column.

Here is some example data of how I would like everything to be-

```
      A      |       B       |        C          |     D
-------------------------------------------------------------
flag counter | consent given | consent not given | other flag
-------------------------------------------------------------
      0      |       1       |        0          |     0
      1      |       1       |        0          |     1
      1      |       0       |        1          |     0
      2      |       0       |        1          |     1
      1      |               |                   |     1
      0      |               |                   |     0
```

Formulas I am currently using (all formulas only look at cells in their same row- i.e. A1 uses B1, C1, D1, while A2 uses B2, C2, D2. I'll list A1 below for simplicity):

**A1:** =C1+D1

**B1:** This is raw data. Values are 1, 0, or empty

**C1:** This is what I'm looking for. I want something along the lines of =IF(B1=1, 0, IF(B1=0, 1, `<empty`>)) where `<empty`> is a pure empty that doesn't break the addition formula in column A (empty string breaks the formula). I've found formulas that leave the empty string or a 0, and either of those work in this instance. I want 1 -> 0, 0 -> 1, no value -> no value.

**D1:** This is raw data. Values are 1, 0, or empty

Comment: if i understood your question you can use IF(B1="";"") no value get no value...

Comment: @Ferdinando that works correctly to get column C as I want it, but then that breaks the column A formula as you can not add integers and empty strings

Comment: can you post the formula that you are using so far?

Comment: I've tried to do a nested IF along the lines of what I posted for the C1 formula in the OP, but I haven't been able to use anything other than the empty string to leave an empty value, which breaks my addition formula. However, the answer below made me realize I can just use the empty string and then use the SUM formula on just that column which will ignore the empty strings. So in C I'll use =IF(B1="", "", IF(B1=1, 0, 1)), and then in A I'll change it to =SUM(C1)+D1, and that should work

Answer (score 0):

use ABS:

```
=IF(B2="","",ABS(B2-1))
```

And then in Column A sue sum that will ignore the text.

=SUM(C2:D2)

[image]

Comment: That works fine with the SUM() function, but I've been using pure addition (=C1+D1+E1...) since not all flag columns that I want to count are directly next to each other, and pure addition breaks it. However, you made me realize I can just do =CD+SUM(D1)+E1... instead which I believe will handle all cases

Comment: @Hollywood or `=SUM(C1,D1,E1,G1)`

Comment: Ah of course. I don't know why I didn't go with that in the first place, honestly. Thanks for the help